# NameError: name 'x' is not defined (x declared in for loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting below error for below mentioned code:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

list_keywords=['DROP','CREATE','ALTER','COMMENT']
file=open(filename)
for line in file:
    if any(x in line.upper() for x in list_keywords):
        print (x)
```

I'm able to print the line containing any of the strings mentioned in the list.

Below code works.

```
list_keywords=['DROP','CREATE','ALTER','COMMENT']
file=open(filename)
for line in file:
    if any(x in line.upper() for x in list_keywords):
        print (line)
```

Could someone please let me know why print(x) does not work?

Comment: Instead of the `if any(..)` go with `for x in ( v in line.upper() for v in list_keyfords )`. That way, you'll actually get the values in `list_keywords` so you can print them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, `x` is *leaked* into the namespace in a list comprehension (although not in a generator expression), but not in Python 3:

Py 2:

```
>>> [x for x in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> x
2
```

Py 3:

```
>>> [x for x in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Anyway, if you want to get the first value that satisfies the condition then use `next()` instead and for all the values use a list comprhension, e.g.

```
>>> next(x for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 1)
1
>>> [x for x in range(5) if x % 2 == 1]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: How can I print the value of x in python 3.

Comment: @JK Updated the answer, use `next()` to get the first value, or a list comprehension to get all the values

Answer (score 1):

```
any(x in line.upper() for x in list_keywords)
```

The argument to `any` is a generator, and `x` is only defined within the generator.

Comment: Thanks Tobias. Could you please let me know how to get the value of x. I'm new to Python and do not have much idea on generator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but this might give you the information you are looking for:

```
list_keywords=['DROP','CREATE','ALTER','COMMENT']
file=open(filename)
for line in file:
    results = [(line,x) for x in list_keywords if x in line.upper()]
    if results:
        print(results)
```

I tested with this code:

```
list_keywords=['DROP','CREATE','ALTER','COMMENT']
file=['foo','bar','drop comment','zoo']
for line in file:
    results = [(line,x) for x in list_keywords if x in line.upper()]
    if results:
        print(results)
```

Output:

```
[('drop comment', 'DROP'), ('drop comment', 'COMMENT')]
```